# Crockford - array sorting - page 81

Tags: javascript, sorting

```
var by = function (name) {
    return function (o, p) {
        var a, b;
        if (typeof o === 'object' && typeof p === 'object' && o && p) {
            a = o[name];
            b = p[name];
            if (a === b) {
                return 0;
            }
            if (typeof a === typeof b) {
                return a < b ? -1 : 1;
            }
            return typeof a < typeof b ? -1 : 1;
        } else {
            throw {
                name: 'Error',
                message: 'Expected an object when sorting by ' + name
            };
        }
    };
};

var s = 
[
    {first: 'Joe', last: 'Besser'},
    {first: 'Moe', last: 'Howard'},
    {first: 'Joe', last: 'DeRita'},
    {first: 'Shemp', last: 'Howard'},
    {first: 'Larry', last: 'Fine'},
    {first: 'Curly', last: 'Howard'}
];


s.sort(by('first'));// s is [
// {first: 'Curly', last: 'Howard'},
// {first: 'Joe', last: 'DeRita'},
// {first: 'Joe', last: 'Besser'},
// {first: 'Larry', last: 'Fine'},
// {first: 'Moe', last: 'Howard'},
// {first: 'Shemp', last: 'Howard'}
// ]
```

When I actually execute this code, in the sorted array,
Joe DeRitta comes after Joe Besser which kind of makes more
sense as this is the order in which they come in the original 
array. The author says DeRita comes before Besser in the sorted 
array. I don't find this in the errata of the book.

(1) Is this some typo (I doubt it, I guess the code was run)
or just another thing which is a "recent" (implemented in 
the last 5-6 years) change in JavaScript?

(2) Down below the author says: 
"The sort method is not stable, so:

```
s.sort(by('first')).sort(by('last'));
```

is not guaranteed to produce the correct sequence."

Is that really what stable sort is about?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts
I think what happens in the book is two consecutive sorts,
and there's no much chance these to sort in the proper order,
but I think this is not related to the concept of "stable sort".
Is it?

Imagine these two names:

```
[
    { first: "Alfred", last: "Williams" },
    { first: "Barbara", last: "Charles" }
]
```

If we sort by first name, Alfred will be always first.
If we sort by last name, Barbara will be always first.
So... if we do:

```
s.sort(by('first')).sort(by('last'));
```

the result will only depend on what we sort last by (in this case 
we sort last by last name).

Am I misunderstanding something (OK, I admit I haven't thought about 
stable sorts recently) i.e. what's  the stable sort mentioned here for?

Comment: given that the array is sorted based on first name only, the "Joe Besser" and "Joe DeRita" objects are equivalent as far as the sort function is concerned. I could easily understand minor differences in implementation causing the sort order to be different, however I'm not aware of any actual change to the implementation that would cause this difference.

Comment: OK, actually on 2) I think that's exactly what stable is about. 1st we sort by first name, 2nd we sort by last name, and we want the sort by last name to not swap elements which have equal last names (i.e. to keep the ordering from the first sort), if so we call that sort stable. So OK, I think I see the answer of the second part of my own question :).

Comment: just a short note: "sort by" seems to fail with `NaN` values in IE 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With respect to the code `s.sort(by('first')).sort(by('last'));` you say:

> I think what happens in the book is two consecutive sorts

That's exactly correct. If that code was invoked, then the list would first be sorted completely by first name, then completely resorted by last name.

> but I think this is not related to the concept of "stable sort". Is it?

Actually, there is a relation. A [stable sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) will obey the following rule:

> If two items compare as equal, then their relative order will be preserved, so that if one came before the other in the input, it will also come before the other in the output.

In your example, consider the names "Shemp Howard" and "Curly Howard". *If* the sorting algorithm were stable, and you wanted the list of names to be sorted by last name then first name, you could invoke two subsequent sorts. `s.sort(by('first'))` will put those two items in the order: Curly Howard, Shemp Howard. Subsequently invoking `s.sort(by('last'))` *if using a stable sorting algorithm* will compare that last names "Howard" and "Howard", determine that the last names are equal, and **preserve the original order**. That means that any items that have an equal last name would remain in the order that resulted when sorting by first name.

Unfortunately, as noted by Crockford, javascript's [Array.sort is not necessarily stable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), and two subsequent sorts will have no guarantee of keeping equivalent items in their original order.

Comment: Thanks. I sort of got that last night (see my comment above) but thanks for writing it down in some more details.